# parsley error message class override

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

I'm using parsley.js with bootstrap, and I'm trying to change the class for their error messages (according to their documentation) but it doesn't seem to be working. No error messages, but no changes either.

The JS is here:

```
$('#userForm').parsley({ successClass: 'alert alert-success', errorClass: 'alert alert-error' });
```

And the form is basically just:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="userForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" data-validate="parsley" data-focus="first">
<input type="text"id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" data-trigger="change" data-required="true">
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" id="newUserSubmit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `data-validate="parsley"` from the form tag, as I see on their documentation the following :

> Warning : you must remove data-validate="parsley" auto-binding code in your forms DOM to allow you to override the default processing and use Parsley purely from javascript.

And things should work.

Comment: Tried that - the validation works fine, but it's not picking up the classes I want to send. I want the bootstrap error alert classes "alert alert-error" but it doesn't seem to pick it up.

Comment: @Kevin It should work if you set the error class like this : .parsley({errorClass: 'error'});

Comment: what's the difference between that and: 

$('#userForm').parsley({ successClass: 'alert alert-success', errorClass: 'alert alert-error' });

Comment: It has no difference, I was just telling the same method. Well, I would be happy to inspect the code you are working on if you provide a link.